# exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException for text based adventure game

Tags: java

So I am writing a program that is a text based adventure game however I keep getting this error when trying to run the code. My friend has the exact same code but when she runs it on her computer, it works fine. So I don't know why it isnt working for me.

There error occurs here:

```
 currentRoom.displaydesc();
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Option {
    public String description;
    public String target;

    public Option(){
        description = "";
        target = "";
    }
}

class Room{
    public String name;
    //public String current;
    public Option[] Options;
    public String description;
    public String tag;
    public Room next;
    //public String[] key = new String[12];

    public Room(String line){
        name = line;
        Options = new Option[12];
    }

    public void displayLink(){
        System.out.print(name + " : ");
        for(int i=0; i<Options.length; i++){
            if(Options[i] != null){
                System.out.print(Options[i].target+" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    public void displaydesc(){
        //if(description != null){
            System.out.println(description);
        //}
    }

    public void displayopt(){
        char[] key= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'};
        for(int i=0; i<Options.length; i++){
            if(Options[i] != null){
                System.out.println(key[i]+" - "+Options[i].description);
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayInfo(){
        System.out.println("Room: "+name);
        System.out.println("Description: "+ description);
        for(int i=0; i<Options.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Option: "+ Options[i].description);
            System.out.println("tags: "+ Options[i].target);
        }
    }
}


class LinkedList{
    public Room first;
    public Room root;
    public Room current;

    public LinkedList(){
        first = null;
        current = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return first == null;
    }

    public Scanner insertRoom(Scanner scan){
        int i =0;
        //String tag;
        String line;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            line = scan.nextLine();

            //String name;
            if(line != null){
                if(line.isEmpty()){
                    line = scan.nextLine();
                }
                char command = line.charAt(0);
                line = line.substring(1,line.length()).trim();
                switch(command){
                    case 'r':
                        Room newRoom = new Room(line);
                        newRoom.name = line;
                        if(isEmpty()){
                        first = newRoom;
                        root = first;
                        }else{
                        newRoom.next = first;
                        first = newRoom;
                        }
                        i=0;
                        //System.out.println("Adding a new node with name "+line);
                        break;
                    case'd':
                        if(first.description != ""){
                            first.description = first.description+ "\n" + line;
                        }else{
                            first.description = line;
                        }

                        //System.out.println("Adding a new description "+line);
                        break;
                    case'o':
                        Option o = new Option();
                        o.description = line;
                        first.Options[i] = o;
                        //i++;
                        //System.out.println("Adding a new option "+line);
                        break;
                    case't':
                        first.Options[i].target = line;
                        i++;
                        //System.out.println("Adding a new tag "+line);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return scan;


    }

    public Room findRoom(String find){

        Room current = first;  

        while(!current.name.equals(find)){
            if(current.next != null){
                current = current.next;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        return current;
    }

    public void displayList(){
        Room current = first;
        while (current != null){
            current.displayLink();
            //current.displayInfo();
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}


class LinkedListApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList theList = new LinkedList();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            scan = new Scanner (new File(args[0]));
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        String line;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            scan = theList.insertRoom(scan);
        }
        //char[] key= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'};

        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Room currentRoom = theList.root;
        //Option currentO = theList.
        while(true){
            currentRoom.displaydesc();
            currentRoom.displayopt();
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            switch(input){
                case "q": 
                    return;
                case "r": 
                    currentRoom = theList.root;
                    break;
                case "y": 
                    System.out.println("[information]");
                    theList.displayList();
                    break;
                case "z": 
                    break;
                case "a": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[0].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[0].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[0].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "b": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[1].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[1].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[1].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "c": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[2].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[2].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[2].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "d": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[3].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[3].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[3].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "e": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[4].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[4].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[4].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "f": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[5].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[5].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[5].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "g": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[6].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[6].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[6].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "h": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[7].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[7].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[7].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "i": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[8].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[8].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[8].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "j": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[9].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[9].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[9].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "k": 
                    if(currentRoom.Options[10].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[10].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[10].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "l":
                    if(currentRoom.Options[11].target != ""){
                        System.out.println("["+currentRoom.Options[11].description+"]");
                        String room = currentRoom.Options[11].target;
                        currentRoom = theList.findRoom(room);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No option available.");
                    }
                    break;
            }
            //theList.displayList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are right about the offending line of code, then `currentRoom` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

In most of your `case` blocks, you set `currentRoom = findRoom()`, and then loop back to `currentRoom.displaydesc()`, but `findRoom()` has a `return null`, so you get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: so how do i fix this issue?

Comment: That's for you to decide. Is `findRoom()` supposed to return `null`? If yes, what does it mean? What should happen?